# Сервер на Ubuntu отвечает Connection refused. Помогите

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сервер, lamp

В Openserver все прекрасно работало. Связался с VDS и .. 
Индексная страница сайта видится, но после ввода логина и пароля получаю ошибку `Connection refused`. Вхожу в phpmyadmin под учетной записью пользователя, все работает. Подключение в коде также идет через эту учетную запись. Код обычный:

```
<?

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "логин";
$password = "пароль";

// Создание подключения
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Проверка подключения
//if ($conn->connect_error) {

if ($conn) {
    die("Ошибка подключения: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

?>
```

Посмотрел открытые порты

```
root@149793:~# sudo netstat -anp
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19920/mysqld
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3823/apache2
```

Статус вроде listen.

Отвечали мне что mysql работает через сокет, а нужно через tcp.
Вот что в phpmyadmin значится - Сервер: Localhost via UNIX socket.
Подскажите пожалуйста, что можно сделать? Я совсем в LINUX чайник.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить `localhost` на `127.0.0.1`

Возможная причина теперешней неработоспособности: не исключено, что по имени "localhost" PHP пытается коннектиться к `::1`, а мускуль у вас слушает только на IPv4-сокете.

Comment: А интересно, как вы снаружи на апач попадаете? Он только на лупбэке слушает....